# Add function output to a data.table as new columns without naming them

Tags: r, function, data.table, append, multiple-columns

I have a function which takes certain columns from an existing data.table as input, performs a calculation on them and then outputs the result as five new columns.

I would like to append the five new columns to my existing data.table, but cannot find a suitable way to do this without naming the columns (which seems superfluous, since the columns are already named in the output from the function and it already outputs a data.table).

Note: my real function is not vectorised, so I have to use the 'by' argument.

In addition my real function is a wrapper for another function that produces model output, so I have converted that output to a table with `as.data.table(pixiedust::dust(...))` so that I don't have to run it multiple times to get each element of the output.

Here is a toy example:

```
# Load data.table:
library(data.table)

# Create data.table with example data:
mydt <- data.table(region = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                   count = c(0,50,200), 
                   pop = c(1000, 10000, 20000))

# Toy function:
rate <- function(count, pop, denom){

  dt = data.table(rawrate = count/pop, 
                  rateperpop = (count/pop)*denom)
  return(dt)

}

# Apply the function to mydt:
mydt[, rate(count = count, pop = pop, denom = 100000), by = 1:nrow(mydt)]

# which gives:
   nrow rawrate rateperpop
1:    1   0.000          0
2:    2   0.005        500
3:    3   0.010       1000
```

In the above example, the new columns are calculated but they are not added to `mydt`, which remains unchanged.  I've tried chaining:

```
mydt[][, rate(count = count, pop = pop, denom = 100000), by = 1:nrow(mydt)]
```

... but this doesn't add the columns either.

If I try:

```
mydt[, .(rate(count = count, pop = pop, denom = 100000)), by = 1:nrow(mydt)]
```

I get an error because of the `by` clause and even removing it (which I cannot do with my real function) just outputs the new variables, it does not add them to the existing data.table.

I'm sure there has to be a syntactically concise way to do this, but can't figure it out - any solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you need to add new columns, do the `:=`.  Also, not clear why the `by` is needed

Comment: @Akrun if I use `:=` don't I have to add the column names on the left hand side?  This is what I'm trying to avoid...The `by` isn't needed in this toy example but it is for my real function as it is not vectorised

Comment: @IceCreamToucan do you mean add mydt as an input argument to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a temporary object and then use `:=` with the output of `names` on the LHS

```
new <- mydt[, rate(count = count, pop = pop, denom = 100000)]
mydt[, names(new) := new]
```

Another option is to change the function so it modifies your data.table itself

```
rate <- function(dt, count, pop, denom){
  dt[, `:=`(rawrate = count/pop, 
            rateperpop = (count/pop)*denom)]
}

mydt
#    region count   pop
# 1:      a     0  1000
# 2:      b    50 10000
# 3:      c   200 20000

rate(mydt, count = count, pop = pop, denom = 100000)

mydt
#    region count   pop rawrate rateperpop
# 1:      a     0  1000   0.000          0
# 2:      b    50 10000   0.005        500
# 3:      c   200 20000   0.010       1000
```

Comment: this is what I would normally do, but in this case I am using `exactci::poisson.exact()` to get lower and upper confidence intervals for my rates.  That function takes one or two values for each argument, and returns an error if a vector is given instead.  I could extract each element from the function separately and add it to the data.table as you have done above, but this would add unecessary computation time since I would be repeating the function to get each element inside my wrapper function.

Comment: On the other hand, just checked what the overhead is with calling the elements separately and maybe this is the way to go since using `pixiedust::dust()` also adds some computational overhead and it would be nice to avoid an extra package dependency.  The suggestion you had in the comments works for me as well, so will accept this answer.